# Move out-of-view divs in view

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I move a div (that should be out of view on the far right) onto the page when another div is clicked? In the codepen below I want the green div (id = "three") to be off the page, and when the red div (id = "two") is clicked, each div moves over 50% of the page so the green div is on the right and the red div is on the left. 
I can't get the green div to stay to the right or appear when I want it to.

I tried to do something like this:

```
$('#two').on('click', function(){
    $('#three').css("right", "0");
})
```

but it didn't work at all.

Any help is appreciated!

http://codepen.io/amstrudy/pen/VjAQAp

Comment: That line, `$('#slider').css("right", "0");` is looking for an element with an `id` attribute of "slider" — I'm not seeing one in the example.

Comment: Your third div `#three` isn't "on the far right".

Comment: Ito Pizarro - Yeah that was a typo it's right in the code pen.

Comment: akinuri - that's one of the problems I'm having. How do I put it there?

Comment: @amstrudy Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jummqv2j/1/). You can mimic the effect in any way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#three` element needs a `position: relative;` property in order for the `right: -1000px;` to move the element. Once that is added, you have to tell jQuery to make that `.css()` change to `$('#three'), not`$('#slider')`.

```js
$('#two').on('click', function() {
  $('#three').css("right", "0px");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#one {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  right: -1000px;
  position: relative;
  /* this is necessary to position the element using 'right' */
}
#one,
#two,
#three {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can also achieve similar effect by setting/animating the left/right margins on the things you want to move around.

Comment: Yep! This codepen was a very very simplified version of what I'm working on right now so I didn't include transitions.

Answer (score 1):

You should make each square `position: absolute or relative` otherwise, they will not interact with each other being in different flows. Had to change the jQuery as well, you were moving only the green box and needed to move the red one too. The blue one is `index:-1` so that it'll be covered by the red box when the red box moves over for the green one to occupy the right side.

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  right: -1000px;
}

#one, #two, #three {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/ZOaAqY)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve. If so, the main point is to set the position of the `DIVs` appropriately, and also add another `DIV` containing the three `DIVs` of which the `overflow` is set to `hidden` to hide the third `DIV` when it is off the page.

```js
$('#two').on('click', function() {
  $('#two').css('left', '0');
  $('#three').css('left', '50%');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#one,
#two,
#three {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: left 2s;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```